# Batch overlay/merge images with similar filenames

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, gimp

I have 1000+ images in a directory labelled:
x_1.bmp
x_2.bmp
x_3.bmp
y_1.bmp
y_3.bmp
...etc

Ideally, I'd like to overlay all files with a similar name and export as x_P.png, y_P.png, etc. as below. **All images are the same size and none of the colour pixels overlap.**

[image: x_1 example] + [image: x_2 example] + [image: x_3 example] = [image]

I've tried to batch overlay images using a merge-divide script function in GIMP/BIMP without success.  Would `PIL.Image.Image.paste()` be able to do this, or something similar? I'm using Windows and Python 3.7.3

Thanks

Comment: So, you want to convert all files from `.bmp` to `.png`? What do you mean by "overly all files with a similar name"?

Comment: Yes, I'll need to save the final image as a png but this can be done separately if necessary.  All files starting with x should be merged into one image, all files starting with y should be merged into a separate image.  All images are the same size.

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"? Are the images going to be layered on top of each other, placed next to each other, etc.

Comment: Layered on top of each other

Comment: You can't have "layers" in a png file unless you literally have a bunch of images on top of each other and each image is obscuring the one below it.

Comment: Is `x_1.bmp` the red channel and `x_2.bmp` the green channel? Please show your images and the expected result, else we are all guessing and wasting our time. Thank you.

Comment: Are they all the same size? What OS do you use?

Comment: Are there always 3 files for each prefix, i.e. `prefix_1.bmp` through `prefix_3.bmp`? How about writing some code that works out a list of the unique prefixes and showing that?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this for a small number of images. I'm not sure what it would accomplish with a lot of images, though, since everything would jumble together. Anyway, let me know if it helps. I am using pillow version 7.0.0 here.

```
import os
import itertools as it
from PIL import Image

alpha = 0.5
list_of_imgs = sorted(os.listdir('images'))
for k,g in it.groupby(l,key=lambda x: x.split('_')[0]): 
    img = Image.open('images/{}'.format(next(g)),'r').convert('RGBA') 
    x,y = img.size 
    g_list = list(g) 
    for i,item in enumerate(g_list): 
        next_img = Image.open('images/{}'.format(item)).convert('RGBA')
        if i == 0: 
            new_img = Image.blend(next_img,img,alpha) 
        else: 
            new_img = Image.blend(next_img,new_img,alpha) 
        next_img.paste(new_img, (0,0,x,y), mask=new_img) 
        new_img.save(f'images/{k}.png',format='png')
```

Result for three images (dog/puppy, mountain peak, lighthouse):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Working off [the example from the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60581574) I managed to sort this and maintain the RGB values.

```
import os
from PIL import Image
import PIL
import itertools as it


path = path/to/files
alpha = 1
list_of_imgs = sorted(os.listdir('path'))
for k,g in it.groupby(list_of_imgs, key=lambda x: x.split('_')[0]): 
    img = Image.open('path/{}'.format(next(g)),'r').convert('RGBA') 
    x,y = img.size 
    g_list = list(g) 
    for i,item in enumerate(g_list): 
        next_img = Image.open('path/{}'.format(item)).convert('RGBA')
        if i == 0: 
            new_img = Image.alpha_composite(next_img,img) 
        else: 
            new_img = Image.alpha_composite(next_img,new_img) 
        next_img.paste(new_img, (0,0,x,y), mask=new_img) 
        new_img.save(f'path/{k}_P.png',format='png') 


Image.open(path + r"/output_P.png").getcolors()
```

Result

[image: Result]